# Given the function $f:[0,1]→[0,1]$; $f(x)=x^2$, check which one(s) of the properties it has.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, notation

This homework is past due, but I am still fiddling trying to figure this out.

question: I do not understand what the heck the notation of $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$; means. I thought I did, but my repetition states otherwise.

[Here is the image of the problem for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfT3J.png)

Don't even give me the answer to the question itself. Just please explain what **f:[0,1] -> [0,1]; means**. I thought it was all points $0 \le x \le1$. If it is, I have no idea what the heck the answer is.

Any feedback or direction is appreciated.

Comment: $f:A\to B$ means that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  OP is confused and has asked a clear question that can help alleviate the confusion.

Comment: It means it maps the numbers between 0 to 1 to the numbers 0 to 1.  Example 0 gets mapped to 0, 1 gets mapped to one an 1/2 gets mapped to 1/4 and so on.  The domain is [0,1].  The function doesn't map -.1 or 1.2 because those are out of the domain.  The image/range/codomain is [0,1].  Nothing gets mapped to a negative number or a number larger than 1.  Those numbers are, literally, out of range.

Answer (score 1):

It means the domain and codomain of the function are the closed interval from $0$ to $1$. Given any $x$ such that $0 \le x \le 1$, you must have $0 \le f(x) \le 1$.  This is true for $f(x)=x^2$.  You don't have to have that every point in $[0,1]$ is the image of some point in the domain.  If that is true, the function is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it was all points $0 \le x \le1$. If it is, I have no idea what the heck the answer is.

The notation $[0,1]$ means all the points $0 \le x \le 1.$

The notation $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is different.  It means $f$ is a function that takes its input values from $[0,1]$, and its output values are (also) part of $[0,1]$.

More generally, and as someone pretty much already said in the comments, $f : A \to B$ means $f$ takes its input values from the set $A$, and all of the output values are in the set $B.$

Answer (score -1):

It is injective and surjective - both increasing and strictly increasing.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FRm2.png):
[image]